# Stardock Groupy similar software

Tags: plugins

Is there a software similar to Stardock's Groupy in which you can stack windows on top of each other; so it would be like another top-layer of tabs?

https://www.stardock.com/products/groupy/

For reference ^

Comment: You can use tabs in file manager, code editor, terminal, and browser. Do you want to put all of them under the same window with different tabs?

Comment: Yes, it's similar to this picture

https://www.stardock.com/products/groupy/images/Groupy_Sidebyside.jpg

Groupy is only for Windows though and I need something for Ubuntu.